# Button with border (most optimized)

Tags: ios

In my app I need to create a button with a 1px colored border with a corner radius. Width may be different.

Naturally I will create a UIButton setting its layer.cornerRadius and layer.borderWidth.

Is it optimal?
Is there a betterway to achieve this?

Another developer told me that doing this way is expensive.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Compared to using an image this is as cheap as it gets. Go ahead and do it. EDIT: Why not just ask the other developer what he thinks?

Comment: Thanks @ZaneHelton, answer given was "it's too expensive..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UIButton. May be named `ViewWithThinBorder` . 
In its implementation in awakeFromNib method add border corner and width properties.

Now you can go to interface builder select button and set its class to `ViewWithThinBorder` from identity inspector.

This is not only optimized its more reusable anywhere around the interface builder. Also you can change buttons around all view hierarchy from central location.

```
#import "ViewWithThinBorder.h"

@implementation ViewWithThinBorder

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0f;
}

@end
```